# I don't how to solve this triple integral

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

$$\int_{0}^{1}\int_{w}^{1}\int_{y}^{1}e^{x^{3}}dxdydw$$
 I think that I can solve it with spherical substitution but I don't now how to rewrite the limits of integration

Comment: The region of integral is $1 \ge x \ge y \ge w \ge 0$. If you first integrate along $w$, followed by $y$ and then $x$, the integral is trivial.

Answer (score 1):

Spherical coordinates is definitely not the way to go. Try to rearrange the order of integration.

Hint: This region is bounded by the planes $x=1$, $x=y$, $y=w$ and $w=0$. Given the integrand has no antiderivative for x, maybe that means it should be the last one integrated. Can you come up with bounds where $x$ is the last variable integrated?

Comment: The region is not bounded by that planes but you give me a idea, thanks

Comment: @Mdragon except it is, why would you think otherwise?